# mulit plot from different sheets in one chart with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

My problem is that I want to make many graph in one chart but the data is from different sheets.

At the moment my code can only take multi data from one sheet, meaning I can plot 2 graph from one sheet.
My code at the moment is:

```
Sub ChartSheet()

    Dim ChartSheet1 As Chart
    Set ChartSheet1 = Charts.Add
    With ChartSheet1
        .SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E12:E6232, Y12:Y6232")
        .ChartType = xlLine
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "Test Chart"
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "x"
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "y"
    End With

End Sub
```

What I want is to say:

```
.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E12:E6232, Y12:Y6232")
.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D12:E23")
.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet3").Range("Y12:Y6232, G27:G496, H3:5977")
```

and so on.. 
But when I do this my code it only print the last line from .SetSoureData

Hope some of you can help me work around this, Many thank in advarnce :)

**Update:** 
I found abit of a work around by looping but this is not my total answer
But here is my other code:

```
Sub MultiSheetPlot()

Dim cht As Chart, s As Series, xRng As Range
Dim i As Long, chartName As String

    Set cht = Charts.Add
    cht.ChartType = xlLine


    For i = 1 To 3

        chartName = "Sheet" & i
        Set xRng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A20, C1:C20")

        With cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries()
            .Values = xRng
            .Name = chartName
        End With

    Next i

End Sub
```

the problem in this code is that it ignores the last range I define like the C10:C20

Comment: My suggestion is to map the data ranges from the multiple sheets into a single, contiguous range on a single sheet and use that as the source. I don't believe Excel can handle discontinuous ranges across sheets.

Comment: @JessieQuick you can create a chart, and later on create each Series and correlate it's source data range to your desired range. will that solution works for you?

Comment: @Shai Rado Thanks for that idear! it works perfect for me and still fast with no excel crash!

Comment: @JessieQuick so you have it resolved ? you can asnwer your own post

Comment: I will post a resolve as soon as I have a more beautiful code for my fix around from @Shai Rado's idear.

Comment: @JessieQuick can I suggest my assistance ?

Comment: @Shai Rado I posted an update  under my question with what i think you ment.

Comment: @JessieQuick see my answer below on how to define `xRng`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Responding to your latest update, I have a `Sub` that creates a series each time it's called from ***MultiSheetPlot*** Sub.

You can actually add more parameters to this Sub (as long as you remeber to pass them in the Calling).

```
Option Explicit

Dim cht                             As Chart

Sub MultiSheetPlot()

Set cht = Charts.Add
cht.ChartType = xlLine

' call the series creation chart function (each time for each series you want to add to the existing chart
Call Create_SeriesChart("Sheet1", Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E12:E6232"), 1, True, msoThemeColorText1)
Call Create_SeriesChart("Sheet1", Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Y12:Y6232"), 1, True, msoThemeColorText1)

End Sub

' ------ this Sub creates a series to the chart, it receives the following parameters: ------
' 1. seriesName - String
' 2. serValues - Range
' 3. lineWeight - Double (the weight of the line)
' 4. lineVis - Boolean (if you want to hide a certail series)
' 5. lineColor - MsoColorType (using the current's PC Theme colors

Sub Create_SeriesChart(seriesName As String, serValues As Range, lineWeight As Double, lineVis As Boolean, lineColor As MsoColorType)

Dim Ser                             As Series

Set Ser = cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries

With Ser
    .Name = seriesName
    .Values = serValues

    .Format.Line.Weight = lineWeight
    If lineVis = True Then
        .Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
    Else
        .Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    End If
    .Format.Line.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = lineColor   ' Line color Black

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Union() will plot the two graph to one graph, since last night i was thinking is it possible to make all the sheets into an array of sheets with range?

Comment: I thought the whole idea you want to merge the `Range` is to have them in the same series, you dont ? `Range("A1:A20")` suppost to be one series, and `Range("C1:C20")` suppost to be another series on the chart ?

Comment: no, the idea is to plot like 2  graph from sheet1 (with out merging them) and one graph from sheet2.. etc

Comment: @JessieQuick try the edited code, I think you'll like it

Answer (score 0):

My solution is use Name of plage, you can give a name of your range
Like in my photo :
[image]

Everytime when you want to use these datas you just need call them 
Like this plage i gived them name `Poste_EtatDeLaDemande` 
[image]

When i want to use these elements i just call it like `Range("Poste_EtatDeLaDemande")` Excel will find it you don't need tell them where it is anymore ; )

Comment: example in the .Range("Poste_EtatDeLaDemande") you only need the data from 34-100 how til this work out?

Comment: Your plage can be bigger when you insert a new line in it, what ever if you wan to get 34 to 100 you can use 'range("poste_etatdelademande").row' get the position of the first line of your plage 'poste_etatdelademande' and then you can calculate which line you want

Comment: The problem with this is that I cant just do the same on a new workbook contain the same data, I need to go in and plage every new workbook?

Comment: Yes, that what I did with my project.